# express js problem with showing html.index?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]this is my first try with express js and I'm trying to display index.html ho is exist in ''public'' folder I don't know where is the problem
in the side server I have :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

and I reload the server with git bash ;
and I put my index.html inside ' public' directory and I rerun my server I put http://localhost:3000/
in my browser and shows "Cannot get " help  please and thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: share more information, like screenshot   for the error, is it error by the browser or by express is self

Comment: I just added the photos

Answer (score 0):

Please check first console express is running or not then trigger atleast one api like api.get('pathname' , callbak) Using route
Then raise question

Answer (score 0):

you have to make route and render index.html

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.route('/',function () {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the [`index` option](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) to `express.static()` like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public', {index: 'index.html'} ));
```

Keep in mind that express's static rendering doesn't make it into a full featured web server to serve files (like apache, nginx, and others).

Comment: ["By default this module will send “index.html” files in response to a request on a directory. To disable this set `false` or to supply a new index pass a string or an array in preferred order."](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html#index)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as it is when the `public` directory is inside the *Current Working Directory* (i.e. The directory you are in when you run `npm start`, or `node src/index.js`).

If you want to make sure the directory is found wherever you start the script, use a path relative to your script using the native [`path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

For example, if your folder structure is like this:

```
my-project/
 |_ public/
 |   |_ index.html
 |_ src/
 |   |_ index.js
 |_ package.json
```

you need to go up one level (`..`):

```
const Path = require('path'); // <------- add this native module
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening at 3000"));

const publicPath = Path.join(__dirname, '../public'); // <-- get path
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
```

If the directory is in the same folder as your script, you can just do

```
Path.join(__dirname, 'public');
```